# Dos formularios en una sola vista Django - CreateView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Estoy tratando de crear un solo formulario para un `user` que tenga campos de ambos formularios, tanto el `user` como de `userprofile` que cree para extender el modelo.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birthday = models.DateField()
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .models import UserProfile, UserProfileForm, UserForm

class UserProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'userprofiles/user_create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = UserProfileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'userprofiles/user_create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = UserForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Vista, aquí usando `form` me muestra en ambos el mismo formulario que es el de modelo de `User` que trae Django.

```
<form action="{% url 'users:user_create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }} 
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Crear Usuario</button>
</form>
```

Sé que tal vez pueda hacerse con `Formset` o con `prefix` de la vista basada en clase, pero creo que el `prefix` no es necesariamente para eso y no lo tengo del todo claro.

Saludos!

Comment: Se puede, pero no uses las 'built-in' clases, usa un View o TemplateView y personaliza el context y el metodo post

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que en Django, llamamos `form` a los formularios **por costumbre**, pero asi como no puede haber dos usuarios ikenshu en un mismo sitio, no puede haber dos formularios llamados `form` en una vista.

Nada te impide llamar al primer formulario `unicornio` y al segundo `dragon`.

Ahora bien, los formularios son objetos, instancias de una clase `Form`, por lo tanto puedes **agregarlos al *contexto*** de una vista.

Podrías intentar esta respuesta StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497693/django-can-class-based-views-accept-two-forms-at-a-time/24011448#24011448

Y al usarlo, harías algo como esto:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import UserProfile, UserProfileForm, UserForm


class UserProfileCreateView(MultiFormsView):
    template_name = 'userprofiles/user_create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = {
        'dragon': UserProfileForm,
        'unicornio': UserForm
    }
```

> **Nota Importante**:
>   Este ejemplo no considera la forma en la que los formularios se validan.

> **Nota 2**:
>   Considera la posibilidad de usar un modelo en lugar de dos, extendiendo el modelo `User` con los campos que usas en el modelo `Profile`.

Comment: Voy a intentar lo que dices el lunes gracias por la respuesta <3 pero a que te refiere a con la segunda nota, dices de usar un solo ModelForm o como?

Comment: Un solo modelo `User` y ahí agregar los campos que pones en el modelo `UserProfile`.

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, porque el modelo que tengo extiende del modelo User de Django o dices hacer uno custom? x.x sorry las dudas

Comment: Borra, desecha el modelo `UserProfile`. No lo uses más. Usa solo el modelo `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, para trabajar con la clase profile deberías pensar en una vista de actualización y no de creación del profile. Para crear el profile, simplemente debes generar una nueva instancia cuando se ejecute la signal post_save de user, podría ser algo así:

```python
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

En cuanto a  vista de actualización la generaré a partir de View, ya que la solución a este tipo de problemas se visualiza mejor:

```python
class ProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')

        messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, en el siguiente enlace te dejo más información sobre [como extender los usuarios de Django](http://miguelgomez.io/python/extender-user-django/).

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Dices de crear solamente un formulario para el registro y después mostrar uno en el perfil para actualizar otros campos, así también podría ser no?